# R: how to find what S3 method will be called on an object?

Tags: r, methods

I know about `methods()`, which returns all methods for a given class. Suppose I have `x` and I want to know what method will be called when I call `foo(x)`. Is there a oneliner or package that will do this?

The shortest I can think of is:

```
sapply(class(x), function(y) try(getS3method('foo', y), silent = TRUE))
```

and then to check the class of the results... but is there not a builtin for this?

**Update**

The full one liner would be:

```
fm <- function (x, method) { 
  cls <- c(class(x), 'default')
  results <- lapply(cls, function(y) try(getS3method(method, y), silent = TRUE))
  Find(function (x) class(x) != 'try-error', results)   
}
```

This will work with most things but be aware that it might fail with some complex objects. For example, according to `?S3Methods`, calling `foo` on `matrix(1:4, 2, 2)` would try `foo.matrix`, then `foo.numeric`, then `foo.default`; whereas this code will just look for `foo.matrix` and `foo.default`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`findMethod` defined below is not a one-liner but its body has only 4 lines  of code (and if we required that the generic be passed as a character string it could be reduced to 3 lines of code).  It will return a character string representing the name of the method that would be dispatched by the input generic given that generic and its arguments.  (Replace the last line of the body of `findMethod` with `get(X(...))` if you want to return the method itself instead.) Internally it creates a generic X and an X method corresponding to each method of the input generic such that each X method returns the name of the method of the input generic that would be run.  The X generic and its methods are all created within the `findMethod` function so they disappear when `findMethod` exits.  To get the result we just run X with the input argument(s) as the final line of the `findMethod` function body.

```
findMethod <- function(generic, ...) {
  ch <- deparse(substitute(generic))
  f <- X <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("X")
  for(m in methods(ch)) assign(sub(ch, "X", m, fixed = TRUE), "body<-"(f, value = m))
  X(...)
}
```

Now test it.  (Note that the one-liner in the question fails with an error in several of these tests but `findMethod` gives the expected result.)

```
findMethod(as.ts, iris)
## [1] "as.ts.default"

findMethod(print, iris)
## [1] "print.data.frame"

findMethod(print, Sys.time())
## [1] "print.POSIXct"

findMethod(print, 22)
## [1] "print.default"

# in this example it looks at 2nd component of class vector as no print.ordered exists
class(ordered(3))
## [1] "ordered" "factor" 
findMethod(print, ordered(3))
## [1] "print.factor"

findMethod(`[`, BOD, 1:2, "Time")
## [1] "[.data.frame"
```

Comment: Interesting. I tweaked my oneliner in response to your comments. Your way of doing things is quite unusual, what motivates it? I know there's a reason...

Comment: I would not characterize it as unusual.  It works by using R's own S3 mechanism to find the correct method and by doing so it makes it more likely that it works the same way that R does. (Note that the revised code in the question still has problems and is no longer a one-liner.)

Comment: Ah... I get it. Nice. What are the problems? I'll revise my question.

Comment: Test it out using the tests in my answer.

Comment: I did: `fm(iris, 'as.ts')` returns the `as.ts.default` function, and so forth. None of them seem to be wrong? But I am pretty sure that something like a matrix wouldn't work.

Comment: OK.  There were no tests provided in the question so I had tried `fm(iris, as.ts)` which returns NULL.

Comment: I notice that it does not work for some special functions like `[`. Anyone have an idea how to make it work for these? 3rd line of the function doesn't make any sense to me, so I couldn't modify it to work.

Comment: Have fixed. See last example.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
s3_method <- function(generic, class, env = parent.frame()) {
  fn <- get(generic, envir = env)

  ns <- asNamespace(topenv(fn))
  tbl <- ns$.__S3MethodsTable__.

  for (c in class) {
    name <- paste0(generic, ".", c)
    if (exists(name, envir = tbl, inherits = FALSE)) {
      return(get(name, envir = tbl))
    }
    if (exists(name, envir = globalenv(), inherits = FALSE)) {
      return(get(name, envir = globalenv()))
    }
  }

  NULL
}
```

For simplicity this doesn't return methods defined by assignment in the calling environment. The global environment is checked for convenience during development. These are the same rules used in r-lib packages.