# Which print method is used for atomic vectors?

Tags: r

I don't find which print method is used for the different classes of atomic vectors. 
E.g., why are characters printed with quotes, and numerics are not? 
I don't find a `print.numeric`/ `print.character` etc method.

The reason for it is, apart from the desire of deeper understanding, to create a print method for a new class, and I'd like to understand how the current class is printed.

**Example**: Assigning a new class to the atomic x, makes `print` print the attributes, which I don't want. Understanding which print method is behind this would help me tweak this.

```r
x <- 1:5 
x
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
class(x) <- c(class(x), "new")
x
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "integer" "new"
```

Comment: usually `print.default`

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42742370/8386140) gives a function to find the S3 method that will be dispatched on an object. If you use it on a numeric vector `x` via `findMethod(print, x)`, you get `[1] "print.default"`. If you use it on a character vector you get the same, confirming @alistaire 's comment. The `print.default()` method calls C code though, so it would require more work than usual for the typical R user to understand what's going on. If you just want to make a print method for your custom class that doesn't print the class attribute, it should be straightforward

Comment: Thanks both, that's helpful. I wondered about print.default, but was not so sure because of the different results for character and numerics. Guess I have to accept this as a mystery

Comment: The C code isn't impossible to find:  http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-4.pdf, page 43.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how deep you want to go into the explanation Tjebo. For the built-in classes, the `print.default` method is called, which in turn calls some internal C code.

The internal C function that is called in `print.default` is defined [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/7fbd35d0c77d3b3ee85e8f370a61a3e0e1248870/src/main/print.c#L215). The C code takes the R object as a `SEXP` object and decides what to do with it by checking its fundamental type and using a switch statement to determine the format of printing to the console using the C print method `sprintf`.

It's no mystery, since you can trace the code through quite easily, but essentially the print methods for the basic types are defined in C code and you can't change them directly.

However, that doesn't stop you from overriding them by defining your own print methods for the built in types:

```r
print.character <- function(x) cat("I print characters")
print("a")
#> I print characters
```

And you don't need to settle for the default printing of attributes, etc, when you define a new class:

```
x <- 1:5 
class(x) <- c(class(x), "new")
print.new <- function(x) cat("My fancy new class prints like this:", x)
x
#> My fancy new class prints like this: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: By lucky coincidence, I just came across a small comment by user IRTFM on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19146177/7941188. the suggested idea would indeed provide a very straight forward solution how to print like the print.default: e.g., `print.new=function(x){ print.default(as.character(x)) }`